# Should you necessarily be page admin to post on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post data to a Facebook Page using Graph API even if I do not have Admin rights on the page.
I am familiar with pages with stricter permissions.
For example, http://www.facebook.com/barackobama is a page where I cannot post data even if I 'Like' it.

My questions are,

1. Can one create such a page with permissions so that any one can post data on it?
2. What is the minimum criteria to post data on a Page? ( Should I be the Page Admin / I Like Page / Anyone with a Facebook login)
3. If I cannot post to a page without admin permission, can I use public groups to post data via Graph API?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated?

Disclaimer: I [asked this on Facebook Developer forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=98166) also. Seems like the average response time is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Page admins can specify if Users can or cannot post on its wall, even if they are fans already.
2. The criteria is:

   - You like the page
   - The admin settings for "users can post on page wall" is checked
3. No you cannot use groups to publish to a page.

The questions might be irrelevant if you really wanted to post to a page. Your questions mean that you will post on the page as yourself. There is another way to do this, but you will be posting as the page itself.

Get an admin of the specific page to allow your app with these permissions "offline_access,publish_stream,manage_pages". Get his access token, query "me/accounts" in graph API, get access_token of the page, publish to wall using the page's access_token.